# adding new html css to wordpress section from codepen

Tags: customization, css, html

I have my own 3d carousel from my own custom code, and i'd like to paste into WordPress section its code (html css only).

How can i do that?

I've been looking for plugins or any simple instructions (I'm a newbie).

any help appreciated.

txs.

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do. What do you mean with WordPress section?

Comment: By section I mean any part of WordPress text editor,  for any specific page. 
Long story short: my page has been set up already with content,  and I just want to add a custom carousel.

Comment: Then you should try creating a shortcode. FYI: A shortcode is a WordPress editor friendly function which can display anything you want. for example:
`function carousel_function( $atts ){
 return "<div class='your-carousel'>carousel content</div>";
}
add_shortcode( 'custom-carousel', 'carousel_function' );` with this you can put the code [custom-carousel] in your WP text editor and it will display `<div class='your-carousel'>carousel content</div>` when you look on the page. [more info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: txs for tip. Definitely not a newbie task, but neither afraid of diving deep into it... the point is I am in a hurry right now...Would you be aware of any plugin that would accept my code and just handle it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom template for that page and paste your code into the template page. If there is any CSS or JS involved, you can load conditionally for just that page.

Definitely not a newbie task-